# How to loop and display the array data into webpage could not able to display the object data that is available in the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to loop and display the array data into webpage could not able to display the object data that is available in the console

```
import React from 'react';

//const api = "https://reactnd-books-api.udacity.com";

class CurrentBook extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
      this.state={
        books: [],
      };
  }
  render() {
    fetch('https://reactnd-books-api.udacity.com/books', 
      { headers: { 'Authorization': 'whatever-you-want' }}
    )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {this.setState({ books: res });})

  //const book= obj.books[0];

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Currently Reading </h2>
        <h3>{this.state.books.title}</h3>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CurrentBook;
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of putting rest call in render function which I think you should never do, you should put in componentWillMount . 
I also noticed this.state.books.title where books should be an array . 
did you mean to do a list of book title?

```html
this.state.books.map(book=>{ return (<h3>book.title</h3>)})
```

this case you should also account for books.lengh>0 so you don't run into undefine problem

```html
class CurrentBook extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            books: [],
        };
        }
    componentWillMount()
    {
            fetch('https://reactnd-books-api.udacity.com/books', { headers: { 'Authorization': 'whatever-you-want' }})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {this.setState({ books: res });})    
    }
         render() {


    //const book= obj.books[0];

          return (
            <div>
            <h2>Currently Reading </h2>
            {this.state.books.length>0?this.state.books.map(book=>{ return (<h3>book.title</h3>)}):''}
            </div>
            )}
}

export default CurrentBook;
```

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` call inside your render, that you have written will send your application into an infinite loop till the server returns an error. This is because you set state inside of the fetch success call, which will in turn trigger a rerender and call the fetch again and then cycle continue. In fact an API call should never be in the render as it will be called everytime your component needs to rerender .

> The best place to have an api call is in
>   `componentDidMount` function as `setState` inside of `componentWillMount` doesn't trigger a rerender.

Also since books is an array `this.state.books.title` will give you undefined. You should rather map over the array and display the titles.

```
class CurrentBook extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            books: [],
        };
        }
    componentDidMount()
    {
            fetch('https://reactnd-books-api.udacity.com/books', { headers: { 'Authorization': 'whatever-you-want' }})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {this.setState({ books: res });})    
    }
         render() {


          return (
            <div>
            <h2>Currently Reading </h2>
            {this.state.books.map(book=>{ 
                 return (<h3>book.title</h3>)
             })}
            </div>
            )}
}

export default CurrentBook;
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to try this out